# How to maintain the uuid of the device when uninstalling and installing an app in ios?

Tags: ios, swift

The problem is that every time I install and uninstall my app a different uuid is generated, how can I make the one that was generated before?
i tryed with this line 
let uuid = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString

but doesnt work

thanks

Comment: How are you generating the UUID?

Comment: With UIDevice identifierVendor more especific
let uuid: String = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString

Comment: Store it in the keychain firsttime.

Comment: @EdgarUribe Don'y put question details in comments. Please [edit] your question with all relevant details.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". Your question doesn't provide us with the needed information to help you. For instance, what does "doesnt work" tell us?

Comment: Apple explicitly intends you to use identifierForVendor for identifying a device, and intentionally resets it when you're uninstalled. Why are you trying to violate that intent? What problem are you solving (you probably are not supposed to solve that problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use advertising identifier, which will be unic accros installations.

```
let id = ASIdentifierManager.shared().advertisingIdentifier
```

There is a way to change this identifier as well, it's a bit difficult to change normal iPhone user.

```
import AdSupport
```

import AdSupport to get it.